# Client Side Encryption AWS S3 Asynchronous

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, encryption, aws-sdk-java

I'm facing a problem of how to initialize the AWS S3 Asynchronous Encryption (SDK V3) using Java.

The documentation was not that clear for me.
This is the code from the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazon-s3-encryption-client/latest/developerguide/using-s3ec-async.html)

```
class v3EnableAsyncClientExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        S3AsyncClient v3Client = S3AsyncEncryptionClient.builder()
                .kmsKeyId(kmsKeyId)
                .build();
    }
}
```

And this is my code

```
public void encrypt(){
    var keyRing = "myKmsArn" // my ARN KMS Key from AWS KMS
    var s3Client = S3AsyncEncryptionClient.builder()
                                          .kmsKeyId(keyRing)
                                          .build();
}
```

But when I run the function, I got this error

> software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to load region from any of the providers in the chain software.amazon.awssdk.regions.providers.DefaultAwsRegionProviderChain@2bf641a: [software.amazon.awssdk.regions.providers.SystemSettingsRegionProvider@4d4a2fba: Unable to load region from system settings. Region must be specified either via environment variable (AWS_REGION) or  system property (aws.region)., software.amazon.awssdk.regions.providers.AwsProfileRegionProvider@2ebabcb7: No region provided in profile: default, software.amazon.awssdk.regions.providers.InstanceProfileRegionProvider@4442e7e0: Unable to contact EC2 metadata service.]

I already create a KMS for encrypt and decrypt. But I still got that error.
[image]

Thank you, I need help

Comment: Plz read the error message: `Unable to load region` Let's try to specify the region param

Comment: @gusto2 the `S3AsyncEncryptionClient ` doesn't have properties to set Region. But the `S3AsyncClient` from SDK V2 have it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup your environment to tell the SDK which region to interact with. You can accomplish this a few different ways, the simplest is to add this line to the top of your main method:

```java
System.setProperty("aws.region", "<YOUR_REGION>");
```

and replace the region with the one you're operating in.

Another, more permanent, option is to update your `~/.aws/config` file to specific a default region. Example:

```
[default]
region = <YOUR_REGION>
```

Comment: Hi, I've follow your instruction to inject the region, access key and secret key to the system property and now the error is no longer about the region. The error becoming 

`Unable to load credentials from any of the providers in the chain AwsCredentialsProviderChain`